# Generalised linear mixed model error (binary response)

Tags: r, error-handling, binary, lme4

I am running a generalised linear mixed model in R for a binary response variable and I am getting an error message.

My code is:

```
library('lme4')
m1<-glmer(data=mydata, REPRODUCE~F1TREAT*SO+(1|LINE/MATERNAL_ID), family=binomial)
```

Where REPORDUCE = binary, F1TREAT and SO = factor each with 2 levels. This returns the warning:

```
Warning messages:
   1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
     unable to evaluate scaled gradient
   2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
     Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined
```

However, the object 'm1' still appears in my Values list. Typing:

```
summary(m1)
```

returns the error:

```
Error in diag(vcov(object, use.hessian = use.hessian)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'diag':
Error in solve.default(h) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[5,5] = 0
```

Does anyone have any idea what the issue is? Funnily, I can run the model just fine if I exclude the variable 'SO'.

Edit:

> with(mydata,table(REPRODUCE,F1TREAT,SO))

```
, , SO = o

     F1TREAT
REPRODUCE control stress
    0      61    167
    1     125      8

, , SO = s

     F1TREAT
REPRODUCE control stress
    0       0      0
    1     186    172
```

The results of a glm are:
    Call:
    glm(formula = REPRODUCE ~ F1TREAT * SO, family = binomial, data = mydata)

```
Deviance Residuals: 
 Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.49323  -0.30592   0.00005   0.00005   2.48409  

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          0.7174     0.1562   4.594 4.36e-06 ***
F1TREATstress       -3.7560     0.3942  -9.529  < 2e-16 ***
SOs                 19.8486  1300.0538   0.015    0.988    
F1TREATstress:SOs    3.7560  1875.5931   0.002    0.998    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 898.27  on 718  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 300.37  on 715  degrees of freedom
AIC: 308.37

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 19
```

Comment: Possibly `SO` is collinear with one of the other variables in your model. I suggest (1) search the web for something like "check for collinearity" (2) post your question (with full data set) on http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: my fixed effects are both factors with 2 levels. I'm not sure I can have collinearity with factors? Likewise, if I remove F1TREAT then SO is the only remaining fixed effect. The model still won't run, and I receive the same error messages

Comment: It's a little hard to guess the issue without seeing the data.  What are the results of `with(mydata,table(REPRODUCE,F1TREAT,SO))` ?

Comment: Also: what are the results of `m2 <-glm(data=mydata, REPRODUCE~F1TREAT*SO, family=binomial)`?  How many observations per mom?  At what level do `F1TREAT` and `SO` vary?

Comment: Please see my response in the original question. Obviously SO is having an effect on REPRODUCE, but it is not returning as significant in a glm

Comment: look up *complete separation* and *Hauck-Donner effect* ...

Answer (score 2):

```
with(mydata,table(REPRODUCE,F1TREAT,SO))

, , SO = o

     F1TREAT
REPRODUCE control stress
0      61    167
1     125      8

, , SO = s

     F1TREAT
REPRODUCE control stress
0       0      0
1     186    172
```

It's been suggested to me that my issue is caused by the fact that some combinations do not exist ([complete separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_(statistics))). You can see that ALL of the plants in the 's' category flowered, therefore SO=s if perfectly precting REPRODUCE. If I change a couple of rows so that one one control s plant 'flowered' and one stress s plant 'flowered' then I am able to run the model and get the summary() output(albeit still with warning messages, probably due to partial separation). The non significance of SO in the glm is due to the [Hauck-Donner phenomenon](http://math.yorku.ca/Who/Faculty/Monette/S-news/0027.html).

I am not sure what to do about this

Comment: This answer might be useful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45803/logistic-regression-in-r-resulted-in-hauck-donner-phenomenon-now-what

Comment: You can deal with Hauck-Donner by computing likelihood ratio tests (e.g. `drop1`) instead of Wald tests.  You can deal with complete separation by setting a prior on the fixed effects via `blme` or `MCMCglmm`: see http://rpubs.com/bbolker/glmmchapter and search for "complete separation" for more information ...

Comment: I have run the model using the `blme` package applying normal priors to the fixed effects    `m1<-bglmer(data=mimulus,REPRODUCE~F1TREAT*SO+(1|LINE/MATERNAL_ID),
           family=binomial,cov.prior=NULL,fixef.prior=normal)`   Should I continue to analyse this model as I would a model built using glmer: by excluding fixed effects and comparing the new model to the full model with `lrtest`? Or is there some better way to report the fixed effects of this model